# how to create a mpd file using MP4Box

Tags: streaming, mp4box

I am new to this GPAC's MP4Box tool. Using this we can create MPD(Media Presentation Description) files for DASH. I dont know how to do this.

Have anyone created a MPD for a video file using this tool?

Answer (score 4):

```
MP4Box -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live -bs-switching multi -url-template sample.mp4#trackID=1:id=vid0:role=vid0 sample.mp4#trackID=2:id=aud0:role=aud0 -out sample_200.mpd
```

1. sample.mp4 is mp4 file which you want to dashing.
2. sample.mpd is output file

Answer (score 1):

They Very basic command will do

```
MP4Box -dash <segment length in msec> sample.mp4
```

For more information read here: [DASH Support in MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/)
 or

```
MP4Box -h dash
```