# how to add audio to video streaming using media source extension

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-audio, media-source, mp4box

I have a mp4 file sample.mp4. I used mp4box to convert it into segments and mpd using [how to create a mpd file using MP4Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398023/how-to-create-a-mpd-file-using-mp4box)
Now my code is from this [source](https://github.com/bitmovin/mse-demo/blob/master/index.html).
After Creating the segments the video is played in the browser. But there is no audio.

The files formed are as follows :
[image: Files formed after conversion of sample.mp4 to mpd using mp4box]

I have two queries here.

Firstly, How can I add audio to this video using javascript in MSE (Media Source Extension)? The video is playing on a mute.

Secondly, The new format files are of the name sample_dash_track1_init.mp4 and sample_dash_track2_init.mp4. While the video plays with the first file and its segments, what is the use of second file and its segments?

```
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MSE Demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>MSE Demo</h1>
  <div>
   <video controls width="80%" ></video>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
  var baseUrl = 'http://beta.insidesoftwares.com/development/video/sam/';
  var initUrl = baseUrl + 'sample_dash_track1_init.mp4';
  var templateUrl = baseUrl + 'sample_dash_track1_$Number$.m4s';
  var sourceBuffer;
  var index = 1;
  var numberOfChunks = 13;
  var video = document.querySelector('video');

  if (!window.MediaSource) {
    console.error('No Media Source API available');
    return;
  }

  var ms = new MediaSource();
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);
  ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', onMediaSourceOpen);

  function onMediaSourceOpen() {
    sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d401f"');
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', nextSegment);

    GET(initUrl, appendToBuffer);

    video.play();
  }

  function nextSegment() {
    var url = templateUrl.replace('$Number$', index);
    GET(url, appendToBuffer);
    index++;
    if (index > numberOfChunks) {
      sourceBuffer.removeEventListener('updateend', nextSegment);
    }
  }

  function appendToBuffer(videoChunk) {
    if (videoChunk) {
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(videoChunk));
    }
  }

  function GET(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
        console.warn('Unexpected status code ' + xhr.status + ' for ' + url);
        return false;
      }
      callback(xhr.response);
    };

    xhr.send();
   }
   })();
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that sample_dash_track1* contains the video and sample_dash_track2* contains the audio.
So your hand written JavaScript player plays only video because there is only video in sample_dash_track1*.

Although I like your JavaScript player - you may want to take a look at https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js?

Otherwise you would have to parse the mpd file and dynamically remux which is a significant amount of work that has been done before for example in the DASH.js library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate your response. Some queries. The dash.js file that you pointed out seems to be playing the file through progressive download for local files. I am putting the url of MPD extension file for it. How does one MPD file helps in playing the file from anywhere ? Currently in the dash.js the file that I am playing is playing from the start and not from anywhere in between. This is problematic as I cannot play the file by seeking points in the middle of the file. Is there a way to add audio source buffer to code I have asked in my question ?

Comment: Processing the mpd file differently prevents the error in my above comment while using dash player. The processing needs to be done using following https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/127

Comment: code used is this https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html